# Add custom instruction to GCC binutils

Tags: gcc, riscv, pulp, binutils

I'v modified RTL of cv32e40p to support my custom instruction.
I've already installed pulp-gnu-toolchain from https://github.com/pulp-platform/pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain

From this tutorial, I think I only need to add line at /pulp-riscv-gnu-toolchain/riscv-binutils-gdb/opcodes/riscv-opc.c

[image]

But there is only little information about each field, so that I cannot fill the MATCH and MASK macro in a proper way. Someone can argue that "why not use that simulator?" but I think cv32e40p has subtle different ISA due to its ISA extension.

Thank's for all